# Matlab Integration - Starting a fake Modbus device

Tags: volttron

For Matlab integration before we have a real connection to a physical controller. I want to start working with a fake Modbus device.

Below the script that I am using to start a fake Modbus device, after activating volttron:

python scripts/scalability-testing/virtual-drivers/modbus.py ~/git/volttron/examples/configurations/drivers/catalyst371.csv 127.0.0.2 --no-daemon --port 5020 --debug-output

Please, how to make the integration with a fake device successfully.

Thanks,

Error message
[image: image description]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message you are seeing is normal output for the fake modbus device. It's successfully setup all of the registers in the csv file as registers on the device.

The next step is to setup a modbus device driver in VOLTTRON and point it at the local host port 5020.

You can find the documentation for the Master Driver Agent (the platform interface Agent for devices) here: http://volttron.readthedocs.io/en/master/core_services/drivers/Driver-Configuration.html

Installing Agents is done with the script scripts/install-agent.py (see the help message for instructions).